# replace string doesn't work when calling the table via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some page called `get_periode` that contains something like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="points">90000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This page is called by the main_page using ajax. But when I called this the replace string function (to make comma every 3 number) doesnt seem to work

this is my replace string function

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
$('.points').each(function(){
    var v_pound = $(this).html();
    v_pound = numberWithCommas(v_pound);
    $(this).html(v_pound)
})
```

It only works if I open the page `get_periode` itself, but when I open it via ajax into the `main_page`, the function doesn't work.
I already put the function on the `main_page`, and on the `get_periode` page

sorry i didnt mention earlier but my get_periode page loaded when i change the select in my main page

Comment: you should call this function only after ajax call completes, try to call it from `.complete()` block of ajax call

Comment: The question when is your code executed? My guess is that it is not in the complete function of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page is loaded via AJAX.

You need to call your function only after the page loading.

Here an example:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "mypage.html", success: function(result){
        console.log("I have got a response!")
    }});
});

console.log("Ciao!");
```

"Ciao!" will be displayed before "I have got a response!", because the call to the file is asynchronous

Put your function in a `<script>` tag inside the loaded page or call your function only after the load (in the response function)